# Getting data from the URL in PHP?

Tags: php

say my URL is:

```
someplace.com/products.php?page=12
```

How can I then get the information regarding page being equal to 12?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the `GET` variables are put into a superglobal array: `$_GET`. You can access the value of 'page' with `$_GET['page']`.

For more information see [PHP.Net: $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 5):

Please check below code to get data from particular URL

```
<?php
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOUR URL');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear whether you're talking about finding the value of `page` from within the PHP page handling that URL, or if you have a string containing the URL and you want to parse the `page` parameter.

If you're talking about accessing query string parameters from within `products.php`, you can use the super-global `$_GET`, which is an associative array of all the query string parameters passed to your script:

```
echo $_GET['page']; // 12
```

If you're talking about a URL stored in a string, you can [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the parts of the URL, followed by [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the `query` portion:

```
$url = "someplace.com/products.php?page=12";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$output = [];
parse_str($parts['query'], $output);
echo $output['page']; // 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats done with the variable `$_GET['page']` (this gives you the value of page, in this case 12)

Answer (score 1):

You can use superglobal variable [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). In this case `$_GET['page']`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['page']`

You have to use $_GET to grab query info.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET['page'] OR $_REQUEST['page']