# Show items related to main menu in a next page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all my Items related to menu in next page.Lets assume I have 
  `3 menus (Engineering,Medical,Programming)`.When I click at programming it ll
  should show all books related to programming in next page.

Please help how to do it?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
          $res=$dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM users");
         while($row=$res->fetch_array())
         {
          ?>
          <li><a href="pages.php"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></a></li>      
          <?php
           }
        ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: <li><a href="pages.php?page_id=<?php echo $row['catid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></a></li>

Comment: Do not comment new question details.  Please edit your question then delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your url looks like `http://www.yourwebsite.com/menus` where you have 3 menus (Engineering, Medical, Programming) when user clicks on one of the menus you could redirect him to a new url, like `http://www.yourwebsite.com/menus?menu=Engineering`, there you can fetch the value of `menu`from url using PHP and perform a new query for that specific menu.

[Getting Data From Url In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902128/getting-data-from-the-url-in-php)

Comment: my url look like <li><a href="pages.php?page_id=<?php echo $row['catid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></a></li>

Comment: Then go through the link I've pasted on how to read data from url in php, basically do $_GET['page_id'] to fetch your page id, store it in variable and perform a query with it. Also pls upvote if you find this answer helpfull.